# iOS + appium java client: Long press TouchAction does not work?

Tags: java, ios, appium

I am trying to automate long press touch action in a native iOS app.

Approach1: to simulate long press in top left corner which did not work.

`new TouchAction(driver).longPress(0,0).perform()` 
Appium logs show no error:

```
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:19 +0000 Debug: Got new command 5 from instruments: target.touch([{"touch":[{"x":0,"y":0}],"time":0.2}])
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:19 +0000 Debug: evaluating target.touch([{"touch":[{"x":0,"y":0}],"time":0.2}])
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:19 +0000 Debug: target.touch(__NSCFArray)
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:20 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:20 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-12-21 17:41:20 +0000 Debug: Running system command #6: /usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.1/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"332523ee-5a1b-427a-8beb-3c150587d08b"}
```

Approach 2: Execute javascript to simulate long press

`((IOSDriver)driver).executeScript("mobile: longClick", ImmutableMap.of("x", 5, "y", 5));`

Appium log exception as follows:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at [object Object].iOSController.touchLongClick (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-controller.js:614:3)
    at Object.exports.touchLongClick [as longClick] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/server/controller.js:371:16)
    at Object.exports.executeMobileMethod (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/server/controller.js:984:22)
    at exports.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/server/controller.js:940:15)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
```

Comment: Might also be possible the nature of the web element changes after being pressed and the long press times out ... try long pressing with coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass 2 arguments to the longPress() methods. They are Element(element in below code) on which you want to hold and Time(2000 ms) how much time it has to hold.

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElementByClassName("xxx");
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(element, 2000).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `new TouchAction(driver).longPress(0,0).perform()` to

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(0,0).release();

action.perform();
```

Make sure you have the right coordinates.